# Missing dependencies tab in android studio

Tags: android-studio

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjF8g.png

My project is named Pudge. When I open Module settings, I select my project and all the tabs (dependencies, etc.) are missing.
This is probably something stupid, but I don't know what.

Edit: adding more info:
The project has a folder named libraries, and in it there is the folder of the library (facebook in my case)

build.gradle of the main project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            res {
                srcDir 'res'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
        test {
            java {
                srcDir 'tests/src'
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

build.gradle of the facebook library

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            res {
                srcDir 'res'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':Pudge'
include ':libraries:facebook'
```

As I said in the comments - after I added the library through the gradle files - its working. But the tabs are still missing.

Comment: Sync your project will gradle and let me know if it is ended with some error. You can sync using tiny gradle button available in tool bar. If it gives some error in Event Log please include that in question.

Comment: Gradle sync completes successfully, but I'm still missing all the tabs.

No errors whatsoever now, actually I managed to add the library from the gradle.settings and the project builds fine.
So this is no pressing issue, but its not normal.

Comment: Can you please include your project structure in question along with the build.gradle file.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question with the info.

Comment: your project structure is still missing please include that as well for clear picture.

Comment: Hm what exactly do you mean, a screenshot of the directory tree?

Comment: Ya, anyhow i think Scott has provided the solution. I was thinking the same that is why asked for the project structure. Whatever, Have a nice experience with AS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your main build file, it has the comment in it about being the top-level build file, so it looks like your main module is located at the project root instead of inside a folder. This is probably what's confusing the Project Structure dialog, because when it examines **settings.gradle**, it expects to see modules in the **Pudge** and **libraries/facebook** directories.

If my assumption about your main module being at the project root is correct, if you change your **settings.gradle** file to this it should work:

```
include ':'
include ':libraries:facebook'
```

Comment: great eyes, you noticed the comment as well .

Comment: Hah that was it. Now the main module has no name in the Project structure window, but the tabs are there. Thanks!